# Language statistics and constructed languages

Tags: reference-request, statistical-features

Natural languages are known to follow some statistical laws, the most famous among them is [Zipf's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law).

Are there published studies of some conlangs with respect to statistical laws of language, not necessarily restricted to Zipf's law, and what are the results of them?

Comment: A quick search on "quantitative linguistics esperanto" returns a few hits, eg https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233561508_Quantitative_analysis_of_Zamenhof's_Esenco_kaj_estonteco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zipf's Law and other similar laws regarding the statistical behaviour/properties of languages are studied in [Quantitative Linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_linguistics). Using QL as a search term together with the name of a conlang (eg Esperanto) will likely lead to some relevant results:

- [Quantitative analysis of Zamenhof's Esenco kaj estonteco](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233561508_Quantitative_analysis_of_Zamenhof%27s_Esenco_kaj_estonteco)
- [Investigating Esperanto's Statistical Proportions Relative to other Languages using Neural Networks and Zipf's Law](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Investigating-Esperanto%27s-Statistical-Proportions-Manaris-Pellicoro/c3c4f7715928038bf3cda07bd4a254d7f61ff6aa)
- [Equilibrium (Zipf) and Dynamic (Grasseberg-Procaccia) method based analyses of human texts. A comparison of natural (english) and artificial (esperanto) languages](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Equilibrium-(Zipf)-and-Dynamic-method-based-of-A-of-Ausloos/203561fe20dc8c6265753894e92a20458245840a)